# Terraform DataSource DataSourceNone with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: vmware, cloud-init

#### Problem

After building an Ubuntu 20.04 (also tried 21.04) template with Packer I'm unable to set new settings when instantiating the template with Terraform. This config had no issues with Debian 10.

#### Packer

```
{
    "builders": [
    {
        "CPUs": "{{user `vm-cpu-num`}}",
        "RAM": "{{user `vm-mem-size`}}",
        "RAM_reserve_all": true,

        "boot_command": [
        "<esc><esc><esc><esc>e<wait>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "<del><del><del><del><del><del><del><del>",
        "linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall ds=\"nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/\"<enter><wait>",
        "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
        "boot<enter>",
        "<enter><f10><wait>"
      ],
      "boot_wait": "3s",
      "boot_order": "disk,cdrom",
      "cluster": "{{user `cluster`}}",
      "convert_to_template": "true",
      "datastore": "{{user `datastore`}}",
      "disk_controller_type": "pvscsi",
      "folder": "{{user `folder`}}",
      "guest_os_type": "ubuntu64Guest",
      "host": "{{user `host`}}",
      "http_directory": "http",
      "http_port_min" : "8000",
      "http_port_max" : "8000",
      "insecure_connection": "true",
      "iso_paths": ["{{user `iso-paths`}}"],
      "network_adapters": [
      {
          "network": "{{user `network`}}",
          "network_card": "vmxnet3"
      }
      ],
      "password": "{{user `vcenter-password`}}",
      "shutdown_command": "echo '{{user `ssh-username`}}' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
      "ssh_username": "{{user `ssh-username`}}",
      "ssh_password": "{{user `ssh-password`}}",
      "ssh_timeout": "20m",
      "ssh_handshake_attempts": "50",
      "storage": [
      {
          "disk_size": "{{user `vm-disk-1-size`}}",
          "disk_thin_provisioned": true
      }
      ],
      "type": "vsphere-iso",
      "username": "{{user `vcenter-username`}}",
      "vcenter_server": "{{user `vcenter-server`}}",
      "vm_name": "{{user `vm-name`}}"
    }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": ["curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vmware/cloud-init-vmware-guestinfo/master/install.sh | sudo sh -"]
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": ["mkdir $HOME/.ssh && echo {{ user `ssh-key` }} > $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys"]
    },
    {
        "type": "ansible",
        "playbook_file": "../../ansible/packer.yml"
    },
    {
        "inline": [
        "echo 'Packer Template Build -- Complete'"
        ],
        "type": "shell"
    }
    ]
}
```

user-data file distributed by packer

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  packages:
    - open-vm-tools
    - python-is-python3
    - cloud-init
  keyboard:
    layout: en
    variant: us
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens192:
          dhcp4: true
          dhcp-identifier: mac
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu
    username: ubuntu
    password: $6$rounds=4096$8dkK1P/oE$2DGKKt0wLlTVJ7USY.0jN9du8FetmEr51yjPyeiR.zKE3DGFcitNL/nF1l62BLJNR87lQZixObuXYny.Mf17K1
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
  user-data:
    disable_root: false
  late-commands:
    - 'sed -i "s/dhcp4: true/&\n      dhcp-identifier: mac/" /target/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml'
    - echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
```

cleanup script called by Ansible provisionner

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# cloud init: move files and change permissions
#mv /tmp/cloud-init/* /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/
chown -R root:root /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/

# cleanup cloud-init data
rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/*

ln -s /var/lib/cloud/instances /var/lib/cloud/instance

# cleanup cloud-init logs
rm -rf /var/log/cloud-init*

# cleanup tmp files
rm -rf /tmp/cloud-init

truncate -s 0 /etc/machine-id

rm /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

ln -s /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
```

#### Terraform

main.tf

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = "${var.hostname}"
  #resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id}"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

  num_cpus = var.vm_cpus
  memory   = var.vm_ram

  guest_id = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.guest_id}"
  scsi_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type}"

  network_interface {
    network_id   = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
    adapter_type = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]}"
  }

  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    size             = "${var.os_disk_size}"
    eagerly_scrub    = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.eagerly_scrub}"
    thin_provisioned = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned}"
  }

  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = var.data_disk ? [1] :[]
    content {
      #All fields in the vsphere_virtual_disk resource are currently immutable and force a new resource if changed.
      label        = "disk1"
      attach       = true
      path         = "${vsphere_virtual_disk.data-disk[0].vmdk_path}"
      unit_number  = 1
      datastore_id = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"
    }
  }

  extra_config = {
    "guestinfo.metadata"          = base64gzip(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/metadata.tmpl", { hostname = var.hostname }))
    "guestinfo.metadata.encoding" = "base64"
    "guestinfo.userdata"          = base64gzip(templatefile("${path.module}/templates/userdata.tmpl", {
        hostname = var.hostname,
        domain   = var.domain
    }))
    "guestinfo.userdata.encoding" = "base64"
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = "${data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id}"
  }
}
```

userdata.tmpl

```
#cloud-config

preserve_hostname: false
manage_etc_hosts: true
prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: true
fqdn: "${hostname}.${domain}"

runcmd:
  - echo hello > /root/hello
  - touch /root/lol
```

```
Cloud-init v. 21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~21.04.1 finished at Tue, 28 Sep 2021 15:55:02 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNone.  Up 19.12 seconds
2021-09-28 15:55:02,449 - cc_final_message.py[WARNING]: Used fallback datasource
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is specific to [VMware vSphere](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80934). To fix it :

```
rm -rf /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg
rm -rf /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg
```